# Web Deploy dump dirPath not working with delegation and a non-Admin user

Tags: asp.net, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm trying to run the following Web Deploy command:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:dump -source:dirPath="C:\Deploy",wmsvc=localhost,username=<user>,password=<pass>
```

I have tried to run this with two users, John and Mary. John is a member of the Administrator group on the box, Mary isn't; the command works for John, but fails with a 401 for Mary.

I have the following set up:

- Mary has full access to C:\Deploy via the ACLs (as does the Administrators group)
- Both John and Mary have been granted access to the C:\Deploy dirPath in IIS using the delegation functionality (see below)

My administration.config entry:

```
<rule enabled="true" providers="dirPath" actions="*" path=".*" pathType="RegularExpression">
    <runAs identityType="SpecificUser" userName="AnAdministrator" password="..." />
    <permissions>
        <user name="PC\John" isRole="false" accessType="Allow" />
        <user name="PC\Mary" isRole="false" accessType="Allow" />
    </permissions>
</rule>
```

When I add Mary to the Administrators group, the command works. But the whole point of delegation is to be able to run deployment commands as non-administrators. I'm able to run other commands (e.g. -verb:dump -source:appHostConfig="Default Web Site") fine for Mary - it's just dirPath that's not working.

WMSvc.log doesn't seem to contain any errors for the failing command - I can see the successful ones fine though. I do see the 401 for the HEAD request in the failed requests trace, but no indication as to why it's occurring...

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I'm now wondering whether delegation is limited to the sites that users have access to - I can use contentPath="Default Web Site" fine with the scenario above, but I can't use dirPath="C:\deploy" (even though the ACLs are identical in both cases - I even tried giving Everyone Full Control to C:\Deploy.) If that's correct it would be annoying, because it would restrict a number of deployment scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zcrar70, you are right: delegation only kicks in once a user has access to a site's scope. In your example, if you had given PC\Mary access to the site (via IIS Manager Permissions), then this would just work.

Can you explain your scenario a bit further? Are you trying to give a non-admin user permission to run specific providers on ALL sites?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this case, the dirPath I was trying to dump isn't actually part of a site. Ultimately, I was trying to do the following: * upload a package containing the new version of the files that make up the site to the server (as well as other files required for deployment, e.g. DB migration scripts, COM components etc.); * point the existing IIS site to the new files. I wanted to run this through a user that doesn't have full Admin access to the server, for (questionable?) security purposes. Not being able to upload to a folder outside of an IIS site rules this scenario out.

Answer (score 1):

Your RunAs identity "AnAdministrator" needs to have permissions to access c:\Deploy, since both Mary and John will be impersonated (if the original identity fails, which doesn't for John) as this user. ACL C:\Deploy for AnAdministrator user and try again.

You can also use [ServerValidator](http://blogs.iis.net/bilalaslam/archive/2010/12/03/servervalidator-a-tool-to-validate-your-server-s-configuration.aspx) tool to check whether your environment is ready for delegated deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the "AnAdministrator" user does have permissions to C:\Deploy - as mentioned above, the command works fine for John (who is also being impersonated as the same "AnAdministrator" user.) I'll try the ServerValidator once I can get it downloaded...

Comment: I just ran the ServerValidator and it seems to fail the "Check Web Deploy Delegation Rules" test - from the log, it seems to fail if it doesn't find delegation rules for almost all providers, whereas I've only set up dirPath, contentPath and appHostConfig. It seems happy enough with the ones I did set up though (they turn up green in the log.)

Comment: I'll get somebody from the WebDeploy team to look at this